# Selenium IDE, XPath not working on specific page

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I'm trying to select element on webapp by using Xpath expression. I've choosen page with maps.

Link for page: http://www.openstreetmap.org/.

I've thought I know Xpath, but nothing works here. For example, I need to search for any city. Xpath to search box is:

```
//input[@id='query']
```

It should work but not. Can somebody explain me why Xpaths are blocked on that page?

Comment: "It does not work" is not an accurate description of an error. Also, please show the code around the XPath expression.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the option By.ID to find the element, If you have an ID there's no need to use XPATH. 
In the IDE just type "query" in the target field.